# How to store freezer burritos?

Tags: mexican-cuisine

I thought of just putting all of them together in a big Tupperware container, but they ended up sticking to each other.

Is there any better way of storing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap them individually in cling-film.

Then you can either box them or just pile them up.

Comment: This will work for short term storage.  Long term you need heavier material, so that water vapor won’t escape as the freezer cycles (resulting in what’s known as ‘freezer burn’)

Comment: tbh, I've never measured exactly how long I keep things, but it's how I wrap anything that doesn't fit neatly into take-away-sized plastic boxes. I've never had burn issues. I've definitely seen it on frozen sliced bread, because my partner seems incapable of re-wrapping it properly ;)

Comment: Or maybe you have a better brand of plastic wrap.  You could also wrap them then put them in a freezer bag or other heavier container

Comment: Saran wrap / cling film / whatever is somewhat water permeable (and much more oxygen permeable than it was when first invented).  Wrapping food in *just* cling film and freezing it is likely fine in the short term, but isn't great for long term storage.  My own approach is to wrap chimichangas in foil, then pack the foil-wrapped chimis in gallon-sized freezer bags.  They happily keep for as much as a year.

Comment: @Joe's cling film + freezer bag is what I do for chicken breasts and thighs and I get away without appreciable freezer burn; it's also convenient for keeping things organised.

Comment: If the storage is going to be relatively short term, you can always just freeze on a baking sheet and then bag. It won't protect them as well, but it will prevent sticking.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to store food in the freezer is to eliminate as much air from around the food as possible, this reduces the risk of freezer burn, which is the result of dehydration from cold dry air. That is where vacuum sealers come in handy, but they are not strictly necessary.  You can remove a lot of air by using a zip top bag, sealing most of the way, then submerging in water to force the remaining air out.  Be careful not to let water into the bag, and finish the zip right when the water is at the top of the bag.  Items can be separated by cling film or parchment so they don't stick together before bagging.  Another strategy is to freeze first, then package.  This way they will remain separate, and if you are using a vacuum sealer, soft items won't get mashed by the vacuum.